# JSON not Sending to File

Tags: php, mysql

I have migrated my website to a different domain. Everything was working until the migration. Now my JSON POST Function returns nothing, its like the file doesnt exists. No code has been changed just the actual URL of the website.

```
  $.ajax({
  url:"/wp-content/themes/atex-assembly/grp-enclosure-122x120x90/load.php",
  method: "post",
  data: { loadDump: JSON.stringify( loadDump )},
  success: function(data){
   wp_send_json_error( 'Error: Invalid data!' );
  console.log(data);
  var ArrayReturn = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(ArrayReturn);
  window.localStorage.setItem('ArrayReturn', JSON.stringify(ArrayReturn));
  window.localStorage.setItem('loadDumpStore', JSON.stringify(loadDumpHash));
  console.log(localStorage);
  window.location.hash = loadDumpHash;
  window.location.reload();
  }
})
});
```

load.php

```
      require_once("/kunden/homepages/41/d753118124/htdocs/atex-assembly/wp- 
      load.php");
      global $wpdb;
      global $current_user;

    // //Get the string from front end to match against database for query
    $loadDump =   wp_unslash( $_POST['loadDump'] );
    $loadDumpDecode =   json_decode( $loadDump );


        $table_name= $wpdb->prefix. 'product_configurator';
        $DBP_results= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE 
        keymap_key = '$loadDumpDecode'");
        $DBP_current_user = get_current_user_id();

     foreach($DBP_results as $DBP_cols){
        $user_id= $DBP_cols->user_id;
        $enclosure_type= $DBP_cols->enclosure_type;
        $keymap_key= $DBP_cols->keymap_key;
        $key_map_loaded= json_decode($DBP_cols->key_map);
        }


      echo json_encode($key_map_loaded);
```

Comment: Are the permissions correct on the files and folders?

Comment: When you say migrated, I'm guessing that you've copied the code from one server to another. If that is the case, the chances are that either permissions are incorrect, or the paths to files aren't as they would seem. My guess will be that the `WP-LOAD.PHP` file isn't in the same location as you've stated in the `require_once`.

Answer (score 0):

The Jquery File needed to be updated due to the new WordPress update.